# How to Know If xpath exists or not:

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

can you help to fix that problem

How can i know and proccess this if the xpath doenst exists

Like... if doenst exista do this, if exists do that

Thank you everyone.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    // set some options (set headless to false so we can see 
    // this automated browsing experience)
    let launchOptions = { headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized'] };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // set viewport and user agent (just in case for nice viewing)
    await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');

    // go to the target web
    await page.goto('https://www.lamudi.co.id/newdevelopments/');

    // wait for element defined by XPath appear in page
    await page.waitForXPath("(//span[@class='CountTitle-number'])[1]");

    // evaluate XPath expression of the target selector (it return array of ElementHandle)
    let elHandle = await page.$x("(//span[@class='CountTitle-number'])[1]");

    // prepare to get the textContent of the selector above (use page.evaluate)
    let lamudiNewPropertyCount = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, elHandle[0]);

    console.log('Total Property Number is:', lamudiNewPropertyCount);

    // close the browser
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Like... if doenst exista do this, if exists do that...

Comment: check if the elHandle is an empty array?

Answer (score 1):

could you try something like below.

```
----
----
let elHandle = await page.$x("(//span[@class='CountTitle-number'])[1]");

if(typeof elHandle === 'undefined') {
    console.log("it is not defined yet, do something");
} else if (elHandle.length > 0) {
    console.log("you have a greater than zero length array, do something");
}
----
----
```

hope it might help.